# Any Downsides to making a method generic where the method return type includes an interface?

Tags: c#, generics

Consider a method like:

```
IEnumerable<IFoo> DoSomethingRequiringIFooInterface(IEnumerable<IFoo> foos)
```

where the method uses the IFoo interface (perhaps for filtering or sorting), but it's not creating new objects implementing IFoo.

Wouldn't it *always* be better to make the method generic like:

```
IEnumerable<TFoo> DoSomethingRequiringIFooInterface<TFoo>(IEnumerable<TFoo> foos)
    where TFoo : IFoo
```

so that the client can preserve type? Or are there some downsides (or some cases) where you *wouldn't* want to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You wouldn't want to do this if the returned values could be a different type of object implementing IFoo than the objects being passed in.  The generic version is appropriate if all of the elements returned need to have at least the same level of type specificity as the elements passed in.  So, if your function always returns SpecialFoo if provided SpecialFoo, the generic method is more appropriate, as it's more tightly constrained.

Comment: This is not correct answer as someone who is using this method can always do: DoSomethingRequiringIFooInterface<IFoo>(...); So generic metod can be same as non-generic, but provides user an option to put more constraints if he wants.

Comment: @watbywbarif, no, the contract of the generic method is saying 'if you give me some objects of type T, I will provide some objects of type T in return'.  The means if you call Method<SpecialFoo>, the method _has_ to return objects of type or a type deriving from SpecialFoo.  Compare this to the non-generic case, where the user can provide SpecialFoo instances and get WrapperFoo instances in return (since they implement IFoo.)  There are cases where you might want to do the latter (such as when using a decorator pattern to add functionality to a class implementing an interface.)

Comment: I don't see how this changes things as he said that he is not creating new objects. Decorator pattern involves creating new objects.

Answer (score 5):

One possible downside is if you want to overload the method:

```
void F(IFoo x) {}
void F(IBar x) {}
```

works fine. But

```
void F<T>(T x) where T : IFoo {}
void F<T>(T x) where T : IBar {}
```

doesn't compile, because the two methods now have the same signature.

Answer (score 2):

Some drawbacks could be possible if you are using Reflection to change or analyze your code, than you have to have more complex code to do this is as complexity of code you are chewing with reflection is bigger.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer generic method because you can always specify method with IFoo, and have same result as with nongeneric method:

```
DoSomethingRequiringIFooInterface<IFoo>(...);
```

And also you give better type safety options to user baecause he can do
(if Foo1 : IFoo) :

```
DoSomethingRequiringIFooInterface<Foo1>(...);
```

And exactly know that he is getting `IEnumerable<Foo1>.`

So this means that generic method is better because gives user more options and has no usabllity drawbacks except for more text he has to write.

Answer (score -1):

This has a downside when you try using it with two different `IFoo` objects. like:

```
DoSomethingRequiringIFooInterface({ new AFoo(), new BFoo() });
```

using the first version this will work. using the second it won't.

Comment: Why wouldn't the second one work? If the collection you pass in is `IEnumerable<IFoo>`, both versions return `IEnumerable<IFoo>`.

Comment: I tried it, and it works fine with both. I had to change the syntax to `DoSomethingRequiringIFooInterface(new IFoo[] { new AFoo(), new BFoo() });`